# is there any way to refresh url with out refreshing whole page

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

i am using prettyfaces 3.3.3, jsf 2.1 , primefaces 3.5
my question is that, is there any way to refresh url with out refreshing whole page like on ajax call

when i click on `h:link` see below code:

```
<!-- do not disturb with this #{subMenuBeanList.subMenuLinkBean}, this gives me pretty:anyMappingId-->
<h:link outcome="#{subMenuBeanList.subMenuLinkBean}" value="#{subMenuBeanList.subMenuNameBean}">
<f:param name="section" value="#{sectionBeanList.sectionNameBean}"/>
</h:link>
```

when i click on `h:link`, it gives me a page ( with this url `localhost:8080/myApp/sectionname/anypattern`) where i have a form with two input fields and one `p:commandbutton` here i submit the form using ajax call
when it is submitted successfully i want url like this `localhost:8080/myApp/sectionname/anypattern?f=2014-15`
is this possible in prettyfaces?

Comment: Don't know if it's possible, but what do you want to achieve that? Different urls should direct to different views of the application. Also it's not a best practice to consider different url for a POST request.

Comment: here i have two input fields one for `2014` and another for `15`  `2014-15` (mentioned above) are the opened financial year of my application basically i am developing a accounts application , when i submit the form using ajax after that i want to show opened financial year(`2014-15`) in url

Comment: So it is basically an url param? Then you should use redirection

Comment: yes you are right, but i want to achieve that without redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refresh the URL without doing a browser refresh, you will need to use something like HTML5 pushstate. You can use History.js for this: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/#welcome-to-historyjs--v18b2-june-22-2013